# Can I specify width in % and min-width in px for a DIV?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar DIV on my web page that has buttons. I have the width of the sidebar set as follows:

```
width: 20%;
```

but when the browser size is reduce then there's sometime not enough space for the buttons. Is it possible for me to have the width as 20% but also specify a minimum in px?

Comment: That's actually the very point of using `width` and `min-width` together.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is pretty common, too. Have fun!

And protip: you can always just try and find out ;)

Comment: I'll ignore the smiley and assert that *Trying and finding out* can never give a **general answer**. Programming by trial and error is what gives the world 99% of shoddy software and crappy web designs working on just a single browser. Use (read, understand, live) the hard specs wherever you can, Luke, i.e. the W3C CSS TR.

Comment: @Jens: Trial and error is foundation of success. The 99% you speak of are just too lazy to *test* what they've created. Designing and testing are two different stages of development.

Comment: @animuson: I heartly disagree. Trial and error, even when tested, gives no answer to "will this work?" It gives only an answer to "Does it work on my machine/OS/broswer/compiler for the particular version and options I'm using?" That answer is next to **useless**. The correct way to program and design is by following and using an agreed upon specification, which, for CSS, is the W3C CSS TR. Trial and error is the road to endless frustration when it comes to cross platform compatibility.

Comment: @Jens: Sorry you feel that way, but part of testing is cross platform compatibility. Those who only test on one browser and/or platform are morons, it has nothing to do with trial and error, which is also not limited to this specific scenario. While writing your CSS by trial and error may not be the best idea, programming (in general) by trial and error is still an excellent method.

Comment: @Jens, there are still some things not covered by theory or specifications.

Comment: @animuson: no need to fell sorry, I like it that way :-) Really, instead of all that multi platform test effort you do (good job, btw!), wouldn't you rather spend these resources on actual feature development? As long as browser vendors claimed CSS 2.x compliance, wouldn't it be nice to program according to that and blame all remaining incompatibilities on browser bugs? You can file a bug report against the browser vendor, pointing to the spec and have a good chance of having it fixed. "Solutions" found by trial and error though are prone to grow into an error with the next OS/browser upgrade.

Comment: @unclenorton: correct; in that case it is best not to rely on unspecified or undefined behavior. Trial and error will only give  a satisfying answer if you exhaust the possible space of OS/browser/version combinations. Too huge an effort for too little return, if you ask me. So I keep designing according to what is guaranteed and try to circumvent that which is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The [W3C CSS recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/) generally does not require that units for different dimensions like width and min-width be the same. (Not quite relevant side note: You can even mix different units for dimensions like padding, e.g. `padding: 2px 1em;`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using “min width”.
`min-width: 20px;` for example.
But if you want its width to always be at least the size of whatever is contained, consider using `display: table-cell;`

Comment: Your answer was better before you added that `display: table-cell` bit... Although I still think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: He wanted to know if you could use them together, not how to use min-width. Also, the `display: table-cell` statement is horrible. Using `diaply: block` is much better for that.